# Greater than date in jsp template

Tags: java, jsp

I have this statement in a jsp form template

```
<% if (forms.getFlDate().equals("10/17/05")) { %>
<jsp:getProperty name="forms" property="flDate" /><br />
<% } %>
```

However, I need to test for a greater than ("10/17/05") date.

I have tried

```
<% if (forms.getFlDate().gt("10/17/05")) { %>
<jsp:getProperty name="forms" property="flDate" /><br />
<% } %>
```

but it will not work.  This is not really my fortay, sort of pushed into it.

Comment: Keep in mind the difference between scriptlets (`<% ... %>`) and JSP tags (`<jsp:.../>`).  You cannot use EL inside of scriptlets; rather, you use full Java code inside a scriptlet.  So really this is a question about how Java compares dates.

Comment: And since this is a Java question about comparing dates, see the [Date API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#before(java.util.Date)).  Also the `.equals("10/17/05")` call will always return `false` since `Date.equals(Object)` can only return true if the Object given is another Date object.  A `String` will not work.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert "10/17/05" to date object first by using `SimpleDateFormat` and then to compare use `<% if (forms.getFlDate().after(myDate)) { %>`

```
<%
    SimpleDateFormat fmt = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yy");
    java.util.Date myDate = fmt.parse("10/17/05");
    if (forms.getFlDate().after(myDate)) {
      // your logic here
    }

%>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to use this "10/17/05" more than once, introduce a variable earlier in your JSP:

```
<% Calendar earlyDate = Calendar.getInstance();
   earlyDate.set(2005, Calendar.OCTOBER, 17, 0, 0, 0); // ** ** **
   Date earliest = earlyDate.getTime();
%>
```

And then later...

```
<% if(forms.getFlDate().after(earliest)){ %>
    <jsp:doSomethingHere.../>
<% } %>
```

Please note this assumes your flDate field is declared as a Date rather than a String.  If it is not, you should follow @S4beR's advice as well for using SimpleDateFormat to convert the String into a Date object.

** ** ** Use the constant for October because month in Calendar is zero-based. *Facepalm*